Determining spectral types from the spectrum as a set
I was recently wondering if we are given a spectrum of a bounded self-adjoint operator as a set, what can be said without knowing the operator? More explicitly, assume we have a nonempty subset $\Sigma \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ such that $\Sigma =\text{spec}(H)$, can we decide what spectral type is associated to a point $x\in \Sigma$? I am assuming for the moment that we only can study $\Sigma$, and don't know how to study $H$.
The questions I am interested is are:

Is $x\in \text{spec}_{ess}(H)$, where $\text{spec}_{ess}(H)$ is the essential spectrum of $H$? Is $x\in \text{spec}_{disc}(H)$, where $\text{spec}_{disc}(H)$ is the discrete spectrum of $H$?

Is $x\in \text{spec}_{ac}(H)$, where $\text{spec}_{ac}(H)$ is the absolutely continuous spectrum of $H$? Is $x\in \text{spec}_{p}(H)$, where $\text{spec}_p(H)$ is the point spectrum of $H$? Is $x\in\text{spec}_{sc}(H)$, where $\text{spec}_{sc}(H)$ is the singular continuous spectrum of $H$?


I think the following claims are true, but I'm unsure.
Clearly $x\in \text{spec}_{disc}(H)$ implies that $x$ is isolated in $\Sigma$. Conversely, if $x$ is isolated in $\Sigma$, then $x$ corresponds to pure point spectrum. However, in this case it seems like you can't deduce, from $\Sigma$ alone, whether $x\in \text{spec}_{ess}(H)$ or not.
Moreover, when $H$ we assume $H$ is defined on a separable Hilbert space, clearly only countably many values in $\Sigma$ can be point spectrum.
On the other hand $x\in \text{spec}_c(H)$ only if $x$ is not isolated in $\Sigma$. However, assuming $x$ is not isolated in $\Sigma$, I don't think we can determine whether $x\in \text{spec}_p(H)$, $x\in \text{spec}_{sc}(H)$ or $x\in \text{spec}_{ac}(H)$. I think that for a nonempty interval $I\subseteq \mathbb{R}$, we have

We have $I\cap \text{spec}_{ac}(H)\neq \emptyset$ if $\text{Leb}(I\cap \Sigma)>0$, where $\text{Leb}$ is the Lebesgue measure.
We have $I\cap \text{spec}_{sc}(H)\neq \emptyset$ if $\text{Leb}(I\cap \Sigma)=0$ but $\vert I\cap \Sigma\vert> \aleph_0$.

Do these claims seem true? Is there any other statements on spectral types of $\text{spec}(H)$ that generally hold when only studying $\Sigma$ as a set?

Maybe you should include some definitions. Personally, I have no idea what "sc" and "ac" mean here.

Does multiplicity make this impossible? A point could both be an eigenvalue and in the continuous spectrum, for example.

@MartinArgerami I added clarification in an edit. I'm sorry for the unclear question.

@Steen82 I just realized that the decomposition is not necessarily disjoint. Even though it seems like the definition of pure and continuous spectrum, in the Banach space case, are disjoint.

For the last two points, I get what you're shooting for but I think it's the wrong way to think about this - I think you should think about this as a property of spectral measures rather than the sets concerned.
Point 1
A result found in this paper of Krutikov and Remling (https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s002200100552) gives a counterexample to $(1)$. Think about $\ell^2(\mathbb N)$. Let $(g_m)$ be a bounded sequence of real numbers and let $(x_m)$ be a strictly increasing sequence of positive integers with $x_{m - 1}/x_m \to 0$ as $m \to \infty$. Define:
$$V(n) = \sum_{m = 1}^\infty g_m \delta_{n, x_m}$$
Then consider the operator on $\ell^2(\mathbb N)$ defined by:
$$(H_0 + V) x_n = x_{n - 1} + x_{n + 1} + V(n) x_n$$
Then $[-2, 2] \subseteq \sigma(H_0 + V)$, yet:

if $\sum_n g_n^2 < \infty$ then the spectrum of $H_0 + V$ is purely absolutely continuous on $(-2, 2)$


if $\sum_n g_n^2 = \infty$ then the spectrum of $H_0 + V$ is purely singular continuous on $(-2, 2)$

So in both cases we get $(-2, 2)$ as a region of spectra, yet in one case it's purely absolutely continuous and in another it's purely singular continuous. So in this case, from the fact that $(-2, 2)$ is contained in the spectrum you can't deduce anything at all.
Point 2
I think the spirit of this is actually true but my proof is a bit roundabout. Let $A$ be a self-adjoint operator on a separable Hilbert space $H$ with spectral measures $\mu_v$ for $v \in H$. We call $v$ a maximal spectral vector if for every $w \in H$, $\mu_w$ is absolutely continuous with respect to $\mu_v$. We call $\mu_v$ a maximal spectral measure.
Lemma 3.15 in Gerald Teschl's "Mathematical Methods in Quantum Mechanics" shows the existence of a maximal spectral vector for any self-adjoint $A$. Lemma 3.17 establishes, combined with the observations below and results earlier in the chapter on multiplication operators in $L^2$, that if $\mu$ is a maximal spectral measure then $\sigma_{ac}(A) = \mathbf{supp}(\mu_{ac})$, where $\mu_{ac}$ is the absolutely continuous part of $\mu$.
Suppose that $I$ is an open interval such that $\mathbf{Leb}(I \cap \sigma(A)) = 0$. Then for each $\lambda \in I$ pick small enough $\epsilon$ to have $(\lambda - \epsilon, \lambda + \epsilon) \subseteq I$, then $(\lambda - \epsilon, \lambda + \epsilon) \cap \sigma(A)$ is Lebesgue null from monotonicity. Then since $\mu$ is supported on $\sigma(A)$, we have $\mu_{ac}((\lambda - \epsilon, \lambda + \epsilon)) = \mu_{ac}((\lambda - \epsilon, \lambda + \epsilon) \cap \sigma(A)) = 0$. So $\lambda \not \in \mathbf{supp}(\mu_{ac})$. So $I \cap \sigma_{ac}(A) = \emptyset$?
From this we can also see that if $\sigma(A)$ has Lebesgue measure zero then $\mu_{ac} = 0$, so $\sigma_{ac}(A) = \mathbf{supp}(\mu_{ac}) = \emptyset$.

Barry Simon has written a lot about the singular/absolutely continuous spectrum, with a theme that for a lot of classes of operators, a typical operator will have purely singular continuous spectrum equal to a closed interval. Pretty surprising, I think he called it the "wonderland theorem".

Thanks for the answer. I think that it least shows that first bullet I wrote is false. I'll have to look on the paper a bit more to better appreciate what you wrote.

@Keen-ameteur if you're still interested, I think I have a proof in the affirmative for Question 2, will edit it in in just a sec

@Keen-ameteur just edited

Thank you very much for your answer. I think this is best answer for my question. I might have to study the lecture notes you linked to more intently.

Partial answer for essential/discrete: when you consider the spectrum as a subset of $\mathbb R$ you lose all information about multiplicity; in particular, there is no more way of telling if an isolated eigenvalue has finite multiplicity. An elementary counterexample is given by the orthogonal projections, respectively, on a one-dimensional subspace and its infinite-dimensional orthogonal complement. Both the pair $\{0,1\}$ as their spectrum but for one of them the essential spectrum is $\{0\}$ and the discrete spectrum is $\{1\},$ while for the other it's the reverse.

Thanks for your answer. I was wondering, from similar reasons, what information about spectral classification can actually be said from the spectrum as a set. Also, whether studying some spectral decomposition from the spectrum as a set is impossible.

I deleted the content of my first attempt, since I give a pretty definitive answer to the question now.
Consider the Hilbert space $\mathscr{H}:=\ell_2(\mathbb{N})$ of all functions $f:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{C}$ with the inner product $$\langle f,g \rangle=\sum_{x\in\mathbb{N}} f(x)\overline{g(x)}.$$
Let $q_x$ be any sequence of distinct real numbers in $[0,1].$ Define an operator $H$ by setting $(Hf)(x):=q_xf(x).$ For any $x\in\mathbb{N}$ the number $q_x$ is an eigenvalue for $H$ corresponding to the eigenvector $$f_x(y):=\begin{cases}1\text{ when }y=x\\ 0 \text{ when } y\neq x
\end{cases}.$$
The spectrum of $H$ is the closure of the set $\{q_x:x\in\mathbb{N}\}.$ So the spectrum could be $[0,1],$ a fat Cantor set, the middle thirds Cantor set, or the set $\{0\}\cup\left\{\tfrac{1}{x}:x\in\mathbb{N}\right\}$ just to name a few possible examples. In fact, any infinite compact set is obtained this way.
Let $E$ be the projection valued spectral measure associated with $H$. Then the Hilbert space decomposes into a direct sum of three subspaces $\mathscr{H}=\mathscr{H}_p\oplus \mathscr{H}_{ac}\oplus \mathscr{H}_{sc}$ where $\mathscr{H}_p$ is the closure of the span of the unit vectors $\xi$ such that $S\to\langle E(S)\xi,\xi\rangle$ is a Dirac delta measure, $\mathscr{H}_{ac}$ is the closure of the span of the unit vectors $\xi$ such that $S\to\langle E(S)\xi,\xi\rangle$ is an absolutely continuous measure, and $\mathscr{H}_{sc}$ is the closure of the span of the unit vectors $\xi$ such that $S\to\langle E(S)\xi,\xi\rangle$ is a singular continuous measure.
The point spectrum is the spectrum of $H$ restricted to $\mathscr{H}_p,$ the ac spectrum is the spectrum of $H$ restricted to $\mathscr{H}_{ac}$, and the sc spectrum is the spectrum of $H$ restricted to $\mathscr{H}_{sc}$.
For our operator $H$ above $\mathscr{H}=\mathscr{H}_p$. So the spectrum is pure point. In particular, it is not possible to determine absolute continuity or singular continuity from property of the spectrum as a set.
If you are interested I can dig up references to the spectral theory (I finally recalled) above.

I'm not sure what you're trying to show by your example. I think you defined an operator on a non-separable space, but I'm not sure what the actual claim is.

@ Keen-ameteur the point really is you can make a lot of weird examples of spectra by using direct sums of operators with very nice spectra. For example, it appears to disprove your claim about ac spectrum following from positive measure of the spectrum.

I assume for my setting that Hilbert space is separable, but I did fail to write it. I think your counter-example would fail if we assume that we have a separable Hilbert space.

not sure about the last bit - as in my answer I think Point 2 is true given non-containment in the pure point spectrum, though I may have made an error
